# Python filter array with multiprocessing

Tags: python, filter, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Right now I'm filtering an array using

```
arr = [a for a in tqdm(replays) if check(a)]
```

However with hundreds of thousands of elements, this takes alot of time. I was wondering if it was possible to do this with multiprocessing, ideally in a nice and compact pythonic way.

Thanks!

Comment: This really depends on the execution time of `check` and the size of `a` and the platform (Windows or linux/mac). You may find that other options such as numpy are faster than mp.

Comment: @tdelaney ideally platform independent, but only necessarily Linux (ubuntu). Check takes ~100ms, but each `check` is independent of everything besides it's input.

Comment: There are always OS concerns with multiprocessing due to the difference in how a new process is launched between windows and *nix by default. ensuring that you always use the "spawn" start method should give the most consistent experience, but you loose out on the possible performance benefit of "fork" (perf only of starting up the new process. once it's running, the speed should be the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a multiprocessing-using parallel filter function `pfilter`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def pfilter(filter_func, arr, cores):
    with Pool(cores) as p:
        booleans = p.map(filter_func, arr)
        return [x for x, b in zip(arr, booleans) if b]
```

`async` means that order of execution is truly independent from each other between the elements.

The usage in your case is (4 cpus):

```
arr = pfilter(check, tqdm(replays), 4)
```

For some weird reasons however, the filter_func isn't allowed to be a lambda expression or defined as one ...

Comment: Any function you pass to a multiprocessing pool must be serializable with the `pickle` module. basically you must be able to `import` it, and lambda's don't have a global namespace they can be imported from, making it difficult. There are external libraries that attempt to do better on this restriction by replacing `pickle` with the `dill` module which attempts to serialize the actual function object.

Comment: Side note: you can also use `p.imap(...)` and stick it right inside `zip(...)` inside the list comprehension, which could save a temporary list in memory (though it would be a relatively small savings assuming it's just a `List[bool]`). Finally you will need to make sure the `pfilter` function cannot be called outside `if __name__ == "__main__":` for normal mp reasons

Comment: @Aaron Thank you a lot for your explanation!! It makes sense! - thank you also for the hint with `p.imap()`!

Answer (score 1):

[concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module provides a nice interface to multithread and multiprocess operations.

```py
def check(a):
  return (a % 2 == 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  array = [1,2,3,4,5]

  from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ppe:
    res = [a for a, flg in zip(array, ppe.map(check, array)) if flg]
  print(res)

# [2,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when trying to group hundreds of thousands of elements, the solution was using https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

The performance improves a lot, but looks like python has some issues when sorting/grouping/filtering big collections in memory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).